# Second Video card configuration

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

## CONTEXT

1. [HP DC7600 with onboard video](https://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.sn=2ua6120s9b&sp4ts.oid=472276&docId=emr_na-c00380853&sp4ts.pn=EH799UC&docLocale=en_US) Desktop PC with Windows XP /
   Ubuntu
2. ASUS EN210 Silent Video Card

## QUESTIONS

How is configuration of onboard / installed video ports typically performed?

- for dual monitors (both onboard / installed video ports are active)?
- use Asus video card only (shutdown onboard)

Does the typical motherboard shutdown its video card automatically when it detects a video card?

I would like to understand the details of this particular configuration as well as the typical thought process (considerations and questions) that apply to the generic pattern.

Answer (score 2):

On-board motherboard video and external video cards don't typically work in tandem.  You are usually only able to use one or the other.  Usually once a video card is inserted into the motherboard, the BIOS will disable the integrated MoBo video port.  You can sometimes choose which video port to use in the BIOS.  You will more than likely not be able to have dual monitors using a setup like that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  If I need multiple monitors (let's say N-monitors), is this typically done with 3 inserted video cards, or is there a special video card that is designed N-monitors?

Comment: Some video cards do support multiple monitors .  Just an example, I haven't tried any of these:  http://multimonitorcomputer.com/top-4-best-videocard-for-multiple-monitor-computers.php

Answer (score 2):

Most desktops seem to have a firmware options (either in the BIOS on old computers or in UEFI on modern PCs) where you can select how your on-board and add-in card(s) will cooperate. Typical settings are:

1. Disable on board
2. Enable on board.
3. Automatic

1 and 2 are clear settings. YOu will either be able to use both of them (and connect monitors to both of them) or only the dedicated card. Setting 3 is a bit more tricky. Most of the time it means "Enable unless a dedicated graphics card is detected".

Brand name PC (HP, Dell, Compaq, ...) are usually much more selective than generic motherboards. If you have a home brewn system expect this to just work. If you have one of those branded once they may *clippy style helpful* not show these options in the BIOS.

However given a standard setup you should be able to use all the ports on the Asus EN210 and whatever port are normally available on your motherboard. You will have to install drivers for both of them. (Which is not a problem unless you are running something ancient like windows XP).